# How to define one-to-many together with many-to-many relation in Eloquent model for three tables in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have three tables:

- projects
- versions
- patches

The relations are:

- projects -> versions (one to many)
- versions <-> patches (many to many)

See the simplified model:

[image]

I need to show all patches for a project. I can do it like this:

```
@foreach( $project->versions as $version)
    @foreach( $version->patches as $patch)
            {{ $patch->something }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

But of course it displays the patches, which apply for more than one version, multiple times.

How can I define this relation in a model and remove duplicate patches? I look for somethig like this (model \App\Project):

```
public function patches()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Patch',
        'App\Version',
        'projects_id',
        '???',
        'id'
    )->groupBy('patches.id');
}
```

---

I have following methods in my models:

**Project**

```
public function versions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Version', 'projects_id');
}
```

**Version**

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Project', 'projects_id');
}

public function patches()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Patch', 'versions_patches', 'versions_id', 'patches_id');
}
```

**Patch**

```
public function versions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Version', 'versions_patches', 'patches_id', 'versions_id');
}
```

Comment: High quality question (+1), its lacking more info on version of Laravel, please add appropriate tag. Also do not use nested `foreach` statements you are opening yourself to a n+1 problem, do a quick research on [eager loading instead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patch.php:

```
public function versions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Version','versions_patches','patches_id','versions_id');
}
```

Version Model:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Project');
}
```

And then...

```
$projectPatches = $patches->whereHas('versions_id', function($q) use ($project) {
    return $q->where('projects_id',$project->version);
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to test it, but it looks like, that the following code works: $patches = Patch::whereHas('versions.project', function($query) use($project) {
 $query->where('projects.id', $project->id);
})->get();

Answer (score 2):

**In your Project Model:**

```
public function versions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Version');
}
```

**In your Version Model:**

```
public function versions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Patch');
}
```

**in your Patch Model:**

```
public function versions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Patch');
}
```

**To show all pacthes for a project:** (Your code for this was correct!)

```
@foreach( $projects->versions as $version)
    @foreach( $version->patches as $patch)
            {{ $patch->something }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**But the above code will produce the N+1 problem so You need to eager load the relationship beforehand**.

```
$projects = App\Project::with('versions.patches')->get();
```

Comment: @Kyslik it did ;)

Comment: Do not encourage people using nested `foreach`, show high quality code, which means show how to eager load.

Comment: @Kyslik Ah. Thanks. On it

Comment: I think nested foreach is not avoidable here, just show whats needed to avoid **n+1** problem.

Comment: But... won't this code still show repeated patches, which is what the OP wanted to avoid?

Comment: Where in this code is reflected the fact that his pivot table is not using the default name "version_patch" but instead "versions_patches" ? Also, the function belongsMany doesn't exist.

Comment: '$projects = App\Project::with('versions.patches')->get();' returns a collection of all my projects. '$projects->versions' returns the following error message: 'Property [versions] does not exist on this collection instance.'